# Dynamic Range Between Blank Rows in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, database-design

I've got a table that looks like this:

```
Date       MaturityDate ZeroRate

5-May-15    5-May-15    1
5-May-15    6-May-15    0.0069999329
5-May-15    5-Jun-15    0.008996562
5-May-15    6-Jul-15    0.008993128
5-May-15    5-Aug-15    0.006744264
5-May-15    5-Nov-15    0.006912941

5-May-15    5-May-16    1
5-May-15    5-May-17    0.006910929
5-May-15    6-Nov-17    0.007017292
5-May-15    7-May-18    0.00712202
5-May-15    5-Nov-18    0.007835916
5-May-15    6-May-19    0.008551509
5-May-15    5-Nov-19    0.009734602
5-May-15    5-May-20    0.010916848

5-May-15    5-Nov-20    1
5-May-15    5-May-21    0.012632521
5-May-15    5-Nov-21    0.013504069
5-May-15    5-May-22    0.014366506
5-May-15    7-Nov-22    0.014935518
5-May-15    5-May-23    0.0154865
5-May-15    6-Nov-23    0.016059181
5-May-15    6-May-24    0.016626256
```

It's split up into evenly spaced blocks with a row between each "1".

I've got a function of the form TestFunction(reference cell, Table Range). I want the "table range" part to refer to the cells in between the blank rows. Is there a way that I can drag down the TestFunction and have it automatically select as a range the blocks between blank rows?

I tried coding something like

```
D2: =IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(C2),TestFunction(B2, INDEX(A:A,LOOKUP(2,1/ISBLANK(C$2:C2),ROW(C$2:C2))):C2),""),"")
```

but this is awfully convoluted and doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: The "blocks" in which column? A? B? C? Or perhaps all, i.e. A:C?

Comment: What do you want your new table to be? Just a copy & paste of the old table? It isn't clear why you need to create a new table if it's already laid out the way you want.

Comment: Is this your own formula or a standard excel formula? If it is your own, select the whole range and then use:   Union(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), 
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)).Select

Comment: You want your "range" to only incude one particular block of data for one given test ? If yes, then you need a criteria to choose the range and use this criteria to build the dynamic one.... I can help you with the dynamic range building but not on the criteria to choose which range to use

Comment: The blocks in column C - I'd want the TestFunction to select the range between the first two blank rows, and then the range between the second and third blank rows, and so on. 

I want the new column to be a list of values calculated by the TestFunction when it has these ranges selected. 

The function is my own formula that I wrote in VBA.

Comment: That is not a VBA formula. VBA is not simply writing excel functions, it is a programming language which can be used to supplement the standard functions of excel itself.

Comment: I don't mean the formula, I mean that the "TestFunction" that I was referring to specifically refers to a function that was written in VBA, which I'm now trying to apply to the values mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, there is a `Property` called the `CurrentRegion` property, which returns all contiguous cells to the one chosen. Using your sample data above, assuming the first block starts at cell `A3` and ends at cell `C8`, a call to `Range("A3").CurrentRegion` returns range `A3:C8`. Similarly, a call to any cell in that group returns the same range. `Range("B4").CurrentRegion` returns `A3:C8'.

Does that help you out?

Comment: Hey this is really useful. Is there a way to use this to refer to contiguous cells in a column, for instance to return range C3:C8?

Comment: If you have a reference to the range A3:C8, e.g. Range1, then INDEX(Range1,,3) will return a reference to C3:C8.

Comment: @varunchandra There are a number of ways. XOR mentions one of them. I personally use the `Intersect` function to return the `Range` object. So, `Intersect(Range("A3").CurrentRegion, Columns(3))` returns a reference to `C3:C8`. Or, if you prefer seeing the column later, same thing: `Intersect(range("A3").CurrentRegion, columns("c"))`

Comment: @user3561813 Yes. Much better than my offering.

Answer (score 1):

Within your function, set the table range = to the total range(rng) (including blanks). Then adjust it using:
    `NewRange = Union(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), _
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)).Select`

This should give you the range without the blank cells

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Excel 2010 or later, and that the data as you give it is in A1:C26, with headers in row 1 and such that the first and last non-blank rows are row 3 and row 26 respectively:

`INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C$3:C$27)/((C$2:C$26="")*(C$3:C$27<>"")),ROWS($1:1)),):INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C$2:C$26)/(C$3:C$27=""),ROWS($1:1)),)`

which, in the first iteration of the formula, will return a reference to the range:

`C3:C8`

and, when copied down to further cells, will return a reference to the range:

`C10:C17`

`C19:C26`

etc., etc.

Note the deliberately offset ranges referenced in the formula (C2:C26 and C3:C27). These should be chosen such that the first (C2:C26) begins in the first blank row and ends in the last non-blank row, and such that the second (C3:C27) begins in the first non-blank row and ends in the first blank row after the last non-blank row.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this array-formula:

```
D2: =TestFunction(B2, INDEX(C:C,LARGE(IF(C$1:C2<>"",ROW(C$1:C2),""),1)):INDEX(C:C,ROW()))
```

Then copy downwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

Create a function that would look  like that

```
Public Function LastCell(ByVal target As Long) As String

    Dim rangeAddr As String

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(target, 1).Value = "" Then
        LastCell = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

   ' Get first Address
   If ActiveSheet.Cells(target - 1, 1).Value = "" Then
      rangeAddr = Range("$A" & target + 1).End(xlUp).Address
   Else
      rangeAddr = Range("$A" & target).End(xlUp).Address
   End If

  ' set the separator of range  
  rangeAddr = rangeAddr & ":"
  ' Get last address of block
  If ActiveSheet.Cells(target + 1, 1).Value = "" Then
     LastCell = rangeAddr & Range("$A" & target - 1).End(xlDown).Address
  Else
     LastCell = rangeAddr & Range("$A" & target).End(xlDown).Address
  End If


End Function
```

then on each of your Dn cells you can type this formula

```
=lastcell(row())
```

and you will get in each row on Dn cell a text representing the range where this particular row belongs to in between the white linges.... use this in your function and resolve it as a range to do whatever you need... job done I believe

Hope that helps